# Reconciling the lack of inheritance in thrift with method definitions in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, oop, inheritance, thrift

I've defined a set of structs in `Thrift`. Conceptually, some of these structs are subclasses of a common parent class. Since `Thrift` does not support struct inheritance, I used the following strategy to define the structs:

## Example

Say `A` and `B` are subtypes of parent `type P`. Here are my thrift definitions to represent that:

```
struct P {
  1: i32 childType,
  2: list<byte> payload
}

struct A {
  1: i32 x
}

struct B {
  1: i32 y
}
```

Objects of `type A and B` are serialized as records of `type P` (the `payload` field would store the serialized version of the object and the value of `childType` will indicate whether the serialized payload is of `type A or B`). During deserialization, the value of the `childType` field would indicate how `payload` needs to be deserialized.

However, this approach poses difficulties when writing code in an object oriented language like Java or Scala. For example, in a function that returns an object of `type P`, I cannot return a result of `type A` or `type B`.

## Question

(i) Is there a recommended approach to deal with this problem? ie, how does one reconcile the lack of inheritance in `Thrift` with `Java/Scala` code that utilizes inheritance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if there is a better approach with Java/Scala, but in our cases adding an additional Thrift struct member pointing to its "super" Thrift struct does what we want.

```
struct Foo {
    1: i32 wtf
}

struct Bar {
    1 : Foo super_
    2 : double moredata
}
```

Of course, that's only kind of a workaround, but we can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use thrift unions, although union support for thrift (at least in some languages) is not great. See [docs](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl#union).

I'm changing your sample a little (B.y is now string) to give a better example. Consider this thrift file:

```
struct A {
  1: i32 x
}

struct B {
  1: string y
}

union P {
    1: A a,
    2: B b
}
```

In Java code generated by thrift compiler 0.9.0, P class has multiple methods that you can use to determine if P contains A or B: `isSetA`/`isSetB`, `getA`/`getB` and [`getSetField`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/TUnion.java#L105-L107) that returns an enum specifying the type.

The generated codes: [A.java](https://codepaste.net/b7kq3g), [B.java](https://codepaste.net/odwxpu) and [P.java](https://codepaste.net/43atoc)

Comment: none of the files A.java, B.java or P.java exist at this point.